# Passing parameter to pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 100

struct thread_param {
    char *f1;
    char *f2;
    int x;
};

void *thread_function(void *arg){
    printf("%d\n", ((struct thread_param*)arg)->x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argvs[]){
    int i, thread_cr_res = 0, thread_join_res;
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = malloc(100 * sizeof(*threads));
    if(threads == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"MALLOC THREADS ERROR");
        return (-1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        struct thread_param *tp;
        if((tp = malloc(sizeof(*tp))) == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"MALLOC THREAD_PARAM ERROR");
            return (-1);
        }
        tp->f1 = "f1";
        tp->f2 = "f2";
        tp->x = i;
        thread_cr_res = pthread_create(&threads[i], 
                    NULL, 
                    thread_function, 
                    (void*)tp);
        if(thread_cr_res != 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"THREAD CREATE ERROR");
            return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

What i want to achieve, is to print all the numbers from 0 to 99, from threads. Also i am experimenting a way to pass a structure as a thread input parameter.

What i am finding curios, is that not all the numbers are shown, eg:

```
 ./a.out | grep 9
9
19
29
39
49
```

And sometimes some numbers are shown twice:

```
...
75
74
89
77
78
79
91
91
```

Can you please explain me why is this happening ?
No errors are shown.

**LATER EDIT:**
I've rewritten the code as @Yasir suggested, using a `pthread_join`. The new code looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 100

struct thread_param {
    char *f1;
    char *f2;
    int x;
};

void *thread_function(void *arg){
    printf("%d\n", ((struct thread_param*)arg)->x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argvs[]){
    int i, thread_cr_res = 0, thread_join_res;
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = malloc(100 * sizeof(*threads));
    if(threads == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"MALLOC THREADS ERROR");
        return (-1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        struct thread_param *tp;
        if((tp = malloc(sizeof(*tp))) == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"MALLOC THREAD_PARAM ERROR");
            return (-1);
        }
        tp->f1 = "f1";
        tp->f2 = "f2";
        tp->x = i;
        thread_cr_res = pthread_create(&threads[i], 
                    NULL, 
                    thread_function, 
                    (void*)tp);
        if(thread_cr_res != 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"THREAD CREATE ERROR");
            return (-1);
        }
    }
    /* Later edit, joining the threads */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
        thread_join_res = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if(thread_join_res != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "JOIN ERROR");
            return (-1);
        }       
    }
    return (0);
}
```

After:

```
./a.out | sort
0
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
3
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
4
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
5
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
6
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
7
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
8
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
9
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

The code is acting like it should. Still I cannot explain myself why the first version of the code was outputting duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr)` to wait for threads termination in order to get all results before main thread exit. Also because of `sizeof(*tp)` you end up with size of pointer to this struct which is 4 bytes long on 32 bit system. This could possibly rewrite other structures in memory. `sizeof(thread_param)` would make more sense to me. 
Also `tp->f1 = "f1";` refers to one constant string. I. e. you don't *save* a string in structure but rather used the same buffer for all your `thread_param` structures. This would be unsafe if `"f1"` is a pointer to variable buffer.

UPD: Yes, comments bellow about size are correct.

Comment: This may resolve the issue regarding the lines that aren't showing at all. Still, why some numbers are shown more than once ?

Comment: Maybe because of `sizeof(*tp)` ? I suppose `sizeof(thread_param)` would make more sense, otherwise we end up with size of pointer to this struct which is 4 bytes long on 32 bit system.

Comment: sizeof(*tp) is the same as sizeof(thread_param) . Anyways thanks for the joining tip.

Comment: sizeof(*tp) means "the size of the thing that tp is a pointer to"

Answer (score 1):

> The code is acting like it should. Still I cannot explain myself why the first version of the code was outputting duplicates.

This is probably related to how stdio is working across threads : in order to not corrupt the output (and generally any other stream), stdio use locking. And if your main thread exit, bad things could happen, like closing the streams, which will have to be reopened / flushed by other threads.

Note that, since there's locking around stdio function, there's contention and printf() call became a kind of synchronization point which is going to change how you program is working.